# python code returns none type object has no attribute error sometimes and works perfectly the other time

Tags: python, string, nonetype

```
def dcrawl(link):
    #importing the req. libraries & modules
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import urllib

    #fetching the document
    op = urllib.FancyURLopener({})
    f = op.open(link)
    h_doc = f.read()

    #trimming for the base document
    idoc1 = BeautifulSoup(h_doc)
    idoc2 = str(idoc1.find(id = "bwStory"))
    bdoc = BeautifulSoup(idoc2)

    #extract the date as a string
    dat = str(bdoc.div.div.string)[0:13]
    date = dst(dat)

    #extract the title as a string
    title = str(bdoc.b.string)
    #extract the full report as a string
    freport = str(bdoc.find_all("p"))

    #extract the place as a string
    plc = bdoc.find(id = "bwStoryBody")
    puni = plc.p.string

    #encoding to ascii to eliminate discrepancies
    pasi = puni.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
    com = pasi.find("-")
    place = pasi[:com]
```

the same conversion "bdoc.b.string" works here:

```
#extract the full report as a string
freport = str(bdoc.find_all("p"))
```

In the line:

```
plc = bdoc.find(id = "bwStoryBody")
```

`plc` returns some data. and `plc.p` returns the first `<p>....<p>`, but converting it to string doesn't work.

because `puni` returned a string object earlier, I stumbled upon unicode errors and so had to use the encode to handle the `pasi` result.

Comment: Moreover, you need to **ask a question** in the question. Don't just dump code on us.

Comment: i'm new here.. confused with the editing section. sorry.i'm trying to be more precise in the comments. figuring out how to use the site:)

Comment: I fear you made it worse. Put text explaining the code separate, with single lines of code that work or not work. Use the preview to see what it'll look like.

Comment: I pulled out your comments into a separate part at the bottom. Try to tell us what happens in proper sentences, not inlined in the code.

Comment: the beautifulsoup documentation says "when there exists multiple tags inside a desired tag we are about to extract, the string function doesn't work. so i made it to strings.. and then worked through them."problem solved".. but now, the same code works perfect for say 100 links. i have a list of over 500+ links... and for each link in that list i run the data extraction function mentioned above.it randomly spits out an error of none type at 'title/date' extractions. when i run the code specifically for that supposedly errorred link, everything works fine then. what is this random nature.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.find()` returns `None` when an object was *not* found. Evidently some pages do not have the elements that you are looking for.

Test for it explicitly if you want to prevent attribute errors:

```
plc = bdoc.find(id = "bwStoryBody")
if plc is not None:
    puni = plc.p.string
    #encoding to ascii to eliminate discrepancies
    #By default python processes in unicode
    pasi = puni.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
    com = pasi.find("-")
    place = pasi[:com]
```

Comment: Some pages do not. but the pages i'm looking for all have the "P" tag. But, this worked when i ran it against the same link earlier. why not now.. the code executes upto "plc.p". I am able to retrieve the message "<p>.......<p>". and now when i convert it to string, it no longer returns.It worked ealier and that is the reason i had to convert the puni string to pasci.